# Any vim command to enter insert mode after paste?

Tags: vim, command

If I use 'p' to paste, vim will remain at normal mode. Is there a command where I can paste and enter insert mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends where you wish to insert text after you've pasted. Paste as normal using `p` and then enter insert mode using `aAiIoO`...

The vim mindset is to enter insert mode as frequently as is strictly necessary.

If you meant how do I paste whilst remaining in insert mode you can use `<ctrl-r>[register name]`. E.g `<ctrl-r>"` for the default register.

Comment: Press twice CTRL-R to insert literal contents of the register.

Answer (score 3):

You can paste *from* insert mode directly, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>. Perhaps this will work for you?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work for me ... using GVim on Windows

Comment: @Eugene M, `<C-o>` and then `p`? Or perhaps the `mswin32.vim` haunts again there in back.

Comment: Actually can't blame this one on Windows ... just dumb user error ... I saw that Ctrl+o took me out of insert mode and I don't know if that confused me or what, but now I see it works fine ... must have been too early in the morning ...

Answer (score 2):

You can map a shortcut to do that, and use it instead to paste:

```
nmap <leader>p pi
```

If your leader key is "," then ",p" will paste and then enter insert mode.

Comment: And *never* use `*map` for such mappings. You have much safer `*noremap` commands, use them.